# making form with buttons inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons and a form with input type inside of it. I want all of them be inline , but I can't do that.

This is what I have:

```css
.btn-registerLayout {
  background-color: #425fab;
  font-size: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 22px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* Search Section*/

.header-search .header-search-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-search-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: .2s;
  color: darkgreen;
  outline: none;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-inline pl-5" style="float:left">

  <div class="d-inline">
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Products" class="form-inline" method="get">
      <input type="search" class="header-search-input" name="SearchKey" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline" style="width:28px !important">
                        <i class="ml-2 bi bi-person-plus-fill"></i>
                    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline">
                        <i class="ml-2 bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i><span style="padding-left:5px"> Login</span>
                    </button>
</div>
```

but I can not make form inline with buttons and result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [Bootstrap 4 - Inline forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms).

Answer (score 0):

Add `d-inline-flex` on the parent to get the elements inline, then you can use spacers or `ml` to space out the buttons from the input.

```css
.btn-registerLayout {
  background-color: #425fab;
  font-size: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 22px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* Search Section*/

.header-search .header-search-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-search-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: .2s;
  color: darkgreen;
  outline: none;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-inline-flex pl-5">

  <div class="d-inline-block mx-auto">
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Products" class="form-inline" method="get">
      <input type="search" class="header-search-input" name="SearchKey" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline ml-2" style="width:28px !important">
                        <i class="bi bi-person-plus-fill"></i>
                    </button>
  <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline ml-2">
                        <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i><span> Login</span>
                    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @nnmmss were you going for something different?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-registerLayout {
  background-color: #425fab;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* Search Section*/

.header-search .header-search-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-search-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: .2s;
  color: darkgreen;
  outline: none;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="d-inline pl-5" style="float:left">

  <div class="d-inline">
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Products" class="form-inline" method="get">
      <input type="search" class="header-search-input" name="SearchKey" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <div class="btn-wrap"><button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline">
      <span>Login<i class="ml-2 bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i></span>
  </button>
    <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline">
      <i class="ml-1 bi bi-person-plus-fill"></i>
  </button>
  </div>
  
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Always works a bit better grouping buttons like that in a wrapper of some sort.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.